# Wordsquare Clearance!

Tags: word-square

### **WORD-SQUARES! WORD-SQUARES! WORD-SQUARES!**

I'm Wally Wordsquare from Wordsquare Motors and I've ordered way too many wordsquares!

I've got to get them out of this lot and I'm passing the savings on to you!

**EVERYTHING MUST GO!**

*For a limited time, you can get not 2, not 3, but **5 wordsquares** for the price of one!*

First, we have the WS1:

> This first wordsquare will have you smiling!
>   It's a collector's item! Very uncommon!
>   It'll leave a rainbow in your eye!
>   It's so comfy, even baby birds can sleep in it!

Next, we have the WS2:

> This one is fast like the wind! You'd think it was on cocaine!
>   This baby's got some history, a long backstory, there's even myths about it!
>   It's valuable, like mineral-rich rocks!
>   Imported from the Americas and their hemisphere!

We've got the WS3:

> This one is even 50% off!
>   Imported direct from the Orient!
>   Such a good deal, you'd think I was fibbing!
>   Perfect for plowing fields or moving livestock!

Check out the WS4:

> Now this one is quick, real speedy!
>   It's got one door that's slightly open, but that's no problem!
>   You should buy this one for God, or my brother Pete!
>   This wordsquare will beam you up through the stars!

Last but not least, the WS5:

> I'm going to need some assistance with this one!
>   This wordsquare is downright wicked! I'm talking villainous!
>   A reminder, this is not pre-recorded! This is being broadcast, real-time!
>   I'm begging you, buy this one! Listen to my urgent requests!

```
Note: These are 5 unrelated wordsquares, each 4x4.
```

Comment: Wordsq**au**re?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answers:

> ```
>  GRIN (smiling)
>  RARE (uncommon)
>  IRIS (rainbow)
>  NEST (baby birds can sleep in it)
>  
>  BLOW (wind, cocaine)
>  LORE (backstory)
>  ORES (rocks)
>  WEST (American hemisphere)
>  
>  HALF (50% off)
>  ASIA (Orient)
>  LIAR (fibbing)
>  FARM (plowing fields, moving livestock)
>  
>  FAST (speedy)
>  AJAR (slightly open)
>  SAKE ("for God's sake", "for Pete's sake" - found by stack reader)
>  TREK (beamed through the stars)
>  
>  HELP (assistance)
>  EVIL (wicked)
>  LIVE (real-time)
>  PLEA (begging)
> ```

Comment: Good job @legendaryNinja

Answer (score 4):

1 :

> GRIN
> RARE
> IRIS
> NEST

2 :(Slightly helped by Deusovi's answer)

> BLOW
> LORE
> ORES
> WEST

3 :

> HALF
> ASIA
> LIAR
> FARM

4 :

> FAST
> AJAR
> SAKE
> TREK

5 :

> HELP
> EVIL
> LIVE
> PLEA