# Wordsquare Theatre

Tags: word-square

[image]

Good morrow, fine puzzlers.

It is I, Winslow Q. Wordsquare IV.

You may know my brother, Wallace, due to his [Wordsquare Clearance!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53148/wordsquare-clearance)

However, as a refined gentleman, I prefer my wordsquares to have rhyme and class.

I have thus prepared 3 wordsquares, in the form of theatre, for those with class and exquisite taste.

---

Act I:

> To stay in one place, where you stand;
>   To write, but where you use both hands.
>   This wordsquare has not come to close;
>   Both ink and pigs, this last hint knows.

Act II:

> The compass points where sun will rise;
>   A music note that reaches highs.
>   To shock and trap inside one zone;
>   The note that comes from mobile phones.

Act III:

> To get things ready for a trip;
>   Your body parts within pain's grip.
>   To cut up carrots on a board;
>   The past tense verb of when you hoard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers:

> ```
>  STOP (stay)
>  TYPE (write with both hands)
>  OPEN (not closed)
>  PENS (ink pens and pig pens)
>  
>  EAST (sunrise)
>  ALTO (high notes)
>  STUN (shock)
>  TONE (phone sound)
>  
>  PACK (prepare for trip)
>  ACHE (body pain)
>  CHOP (cut up)
>  KEPT (past tense of keep)
> ```