# The SS Wordsquare

Tags: rhyme, word-square

[image]

Anchor's away!

Ahoy, puzzlers, I am Cpt. Wesley Wordsquare.

I'm about to set sail for the mainland to see a show at my brother Winslow’s 
[Wordsquare Theatre](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53989/wordsquare-theatre), however I can't seem to decipher this old map to shore.

It's spread into 4 quadrants, and is comprised of wordsquares.

---

North Quadrant:

> In form of stars, give praise or blame;
>   A surface that was once aflame.
>   Hath used archaic form of you;
>   A window to the soul, or two.

East Quadrant:

> The night before the birth of the Son;
>   The drink of grapes that have been done.
>   A palindromic female name;
>   Seven come through pirate fame.

South Quadrant:

> Out, up or into, which ever you need;
>   All paths towards this centre lead.
>   I've got a bad feeling coming on;
>   Perhaps explain where you had gone.

West Quadrant:

> A term for light or with a breeze;
>   A bulb comes on for one of these.
>   An ugly head or all behinds;
>   A toy for one with all nine lives.

```
Note: These are 4 unrelated wordsquares, each 4x4.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers:

> [image]

Some explanations for the less straightforward clues:

> N4: "The eyes are the windows to the soul" is a common saying that originates from the Bible.
>  E1: "'Twas the night before Christmas" is the name and opening line of a poem.
>  S1: "Grow out", "grow up", and "grow into" are all common phrases.
>  S2: "All roads lead to Rome" is a common saying.
>  W2: An idea is sometimes referred to as a "lightbulb moment", and lightbulbs are often used to depict ideas in cartoons and comics.
>  W3: "Rear [one's] ugly head" is another common saying.
>  W4: Cats are said to have nine lives in a well-known myth, and cats often play with yarn.